# django: cannot import installed app

Tags: python, django

My django project cannot find bootstrapform below:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
     # 3rd party apps
    'bootstrapform',
)
```

But the installed bootstrapform egg is in the sys.path (otherprojects is not my django projects):

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['','/opt/pkgs/otherprojects/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_bootstrap_form-3.0-py2.7.egg',]
>>>
```

but the error:

```
sudo /usr/bin/python /opt/pkgs/xxx/manage.py myschd
    ImportError: No module named bootstrapform
```

**Any idea? Thanks.**

Comment: Are you using something like virtualenv to manage this project? Maybe you are trying to run this outsite your virtualenv.

Comment: probably because you're running the manage.py as sudo

Comment: @marcusshep Thanks. Could you please give more details?

Comment: @marcusshep I tried to run the command without sudo, but still the error.

Comment: @Jeasoft I didnot use virtualenv for the project now.

Comment: You can do this. Download the package and put in the same place of your apps. Ex. manage.py, yourproject_dir, app1_dir, bootstrapform, app3_dir

Comment: hi, how you solved that problem, i have same issue here. already installer django-bootstrap-form, but not working